# multiple inputs to field_value_factor in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I am trying to formulate a Elastic Search query using field_value_factor to weigh some fields in the documents.

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "local": true
    },
    "function_score": {
      "functions": [
        {
          "field_value_factor": {
            "field": "title",
            "factor": 1.2,
            "missing": 1
          }
        },
        {
          "gauss": {
            "location": {
              "origin": {
                "lat": 51.5,
                "lon": 0.12
              },
              "offset": "2 Miles",
              "scale": "3 Miles"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "gauss": {
            "creation_time": {
              "decay": 0.8,
              "offset": "2d",
              "scale": "48d"
            }
          },
          "weight": 2
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Any input like:

```
"field_value_factor": {
                             "field": [“title”,"description"],
                             "factor": [1.2,0.8],
                             "missing": [1,0]
                            }
```

does not work for both the fields and the query retrieves same documents as the first one.

Is it possible to input multiple terms in the "field_value_vector" ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use several `field_value_factor` functions, one for each field

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "local": true
    },
    "function_score": {
      "functions": [
        {
          "field_value_factor": {
            "field": "title",
            "factor": 1.2,
            "missing": 1
          }
        },
        {
          "field_value_factor": {
            "field": "description",
            "factor": 0.8,
            "missing": 0
          }
        },
        {
          "gauss": {
            "location": {
              "origin": {
                "lat": 51.5,
                "lon": 0.12
              },
              "offset": "2 Miles",
              "scale": "3 Miles"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "gauss": {
            "creation_time": {
              "decay": 0.8,
              "offset": "2d",
              "scale": "48d"
            }
          },
          "weight": 2
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```